# Excel sheets from a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpoint

I am trying to build Power BI dashboards using data that I get from a PowerPoint presentation.  The problem is, there are 35 slides each having an embedded Excel sheet with the data I need.  My question to the people; is there a way that I can extract embedded Excel sheets from a PowerPoint presentation besides individually clicking in each slide to copy & paste the Excel sheet data?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of your presentation, change its file extension to .zip.
Then unzip it, within the extracted you will find the spreadsheets under ppt > embeddings.

I personally use a tool called 7zip https://7-zip.org/ as it allows you to open any file as an archive without having to change its file extension.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advise.  Unfortunately, it only did it for the first embedded Excel sheet in the slides.  I need to find another way.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Right click on one of the other Excel table and select Object... > Edit/open and when it opens in Excel see where its location is. It could be an external linked embedded file...